# PhoneGap push notification for ios using admin.pushapps.mobi

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, pushapps

How to receive the PhoneGap push notification in ios platform...?

I am using http://admin.pushapps.mobi console for sending a notification , I have configured everything for ios, and used the app token in my javascript file. I had sent a notification from the admin.pushapps.mobi, but it's not reviewing in my app.

I am using the demo given by them..... below is the full link https://github.com/PushAppsService/PhonegapBuildExampleApp

Can anyone please explain where I am wrong ? if there is any other push notification service having PhoneGap documentation, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should check 2 things for PushApps to work as expected:

1. Certificates and provisioning profile matching.
2. You should verify the your AppDelegate.m contains as mentioned in the wiki:

   ```
   #import "PushApps.h"

   #pragma mark - Push Notifications

   #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
   {
      [[PushAppsManager sharedInstance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
   }

   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
   {
      [[PushAppsManager sharedInstance] handleActionWithIdentifier:identifier forRemoteNotification:userInfo  
   completionHandler:completionHandler];
   }
   #endif

   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
   {
      // Notify PushApps of a successful registration.
      [[PushAppsManager sharedInstance] updatePushToken:deviceToken];
   }

   // Gets called when a remote notification is received while app is in the foreground.
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:  (NSDictionary *)userInfo
   {
      [[PushAppsManager sharedInstance] handlePushMessageOnForeground:userInfo];
   }

   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
      // keeps you up to date with any errors during push setup.
      [[PushAppsManager sharedInstance] updatePushError:error];
   }
   ```

Comment: I have used the above coding .,... but i am not sure where i should put these .h and .m files when creating a build using www folder for phonegap ... here is my git hub link where i have build this demo , have a look and reply , Thanks   https://github.com/intrepidwebstudio/aisc-app.git

Comment: Can you send a reference to your generated Xcode project? Are you using Phonegap build or CLI?

Comment: the github link contains all the coding and stuff

Answer (score -1):

Don't use pushapps.mobi give you all limited notification and user plan and after you get more than on milion users then close your account and then tell you if you want return your account more and more money juswsh layer

Comment: It seems like a business idea and not like an answer to question .